# multiple group by in elasticsearch including missing values

Tags: php, elasticsearch, grouping, kibana

I'm trying to do a group by in elasticsearch, by multiple fields. I know that nested aggregation exists, but what I want is including in a certain bucket the record for which the field I'm grouping by is empty.

Say that we have this kind of data structure:

```
SONG_ID | SONG_GENRE | SONG_ARTIST
```

and i want to group by genere, artists.
I would like to have a group for each possibile combination, i.e

group by genre gives me 5 buckets (if genres are 5) plus the bucket in which there are the songs without a genre. grouping then by artist gives me, for each genre, bucket by artists plus the one with songs without an artist.

Basically, I'd like to have the same results that I have using a group by. Is that even possible?

Comment: You need to join your table with other master tables . Then you need to use group by

Comment: Use group by in elasticsearch? Have you understand what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach in different ways to solve your need.

The simplest way would be to index a fix value say "notmentioned" against the `genre` field of `songs` if genre is not present. you can do it while indexing or by defining "null_value" in your field mapping.

```
"SONG_GENRE": {"type": "string", "null_value": "notmentioned"},
"SONG_ARTIST": {"type": "string", "null_value": "notmentioned"},
```

So during aggregation (nested) you will automatically find the count against "notmentioned" for songs not having genre.

Another approach would be to use the missing filter as another aggregation along with normal aggregation. Something like below.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "SONG_GENRE": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "SONG_GENRE"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "SONG_ARTIST": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "SONG_ARTIST"
                    }
                },
                "MISSING_SONG_ARTIST": {
                    "filter": {
                        "missing": {
                            "field": "SONG_ARTIST"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "MISSING_SONG_GENRE": {
            "filter": {
                "missing": {
                    "field": "SONG_GENRE"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "MISSING_SONG_GENRE_SONG_ARTIST": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "SONG_ARTIST"
                    }
                },
                "MISSING_SONG_GENRE_MISSING_SONG_ARTIST": {
                    "filter": {
                        "missing": {
                            "field": "SONG_ARTIST"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't verified the syntax. It is just to give you an idea

Another hacking way could be to treat the missing count (total hits - all aggregation count) as the count against no genre.

Comment: Thanks Prabin. Before asking here, I've tried the same solution you proposed, but it was unfeasible, because my "group by" was on more than 20 fields. I realized that if you are using elasticsearch, you can't obtain the same things as you were on sql. But, for who migth be interested, my workaround was to create one new field on the table which contains the hash of the twenty fields by which I had to do my group by. In this way, different hashes will represents different group, and you can do a normal aggregation by that field in elasticsearch.